# How to detect that a file is ignored?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

Using SharpSvn, I am trying to get an accurate representation of the status of a file.

When I execute `svnClient.Status` on a versioned file without local changes, I get no status back.
When I execute `svnClient.Status` on a non-versioned, ignored file, I also get no status back.

How to tell those two apart? How do I find out that a certain file is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `options.RetrieveAllEntries` to `true` solves this, if - and only if - `options.RetrieveRemoteStatus` is set to `false`. Otherwise, I don't get a status for ignored files.

It will return status "Normal" for versioned, non-modified files and status "Ignored" for non-versioned, ignored files.

```
var options = new SvnStatusArgs();
Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;
options.RetrieveRemoteStatus = onlineMode;
options.RetrieveAllEntries = true;

client.GetStatus(file, options, out statuses);
```

Comment: Message from 8 years in the future: still useful.